# Can't scale a splitted list of values

Tags: python, list, minmax

I got one database, whose values are like the following **253x3**

```
array([[ 75.15000153,  73.79750061,  74.05999756],
       [ 75.14499664,  74.125     ,  74.28749847],
```

I'd like to know which row is the 80% row. So: **202nd row, in my case**

```
lenght80 = round(len(database) * .8)
```

I need to splice the database in two: one which contain the first 80% rows: *eg. from 0-202 row*

```
percent80_data = database[0:lenght80]
```

Now, I need to scale the first 80% values:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_percent80_data = scaler.fit_transform(percent80_data)
scaled_percent80_data
```

The result is what I'm expecting:

```
array([[0.22292997, 0.26680884, 0.21149309, 0.24325282, 0.15966378]
```

Later, I need to create another variable, which contain the remaining 20%+60 previous values of the database training, **(202-60) til 253 row**

```
percent20_data = database[lenght80-60:,:]
percent20_data
```

Now, I need to scale again the values

```
scaled_percent20_data = scaler.fit_transform(percent20_data)
scaled_percent20_data
```

and it results in:

```
array([[8.02431749e-03, 5.65810805e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 3.58560027e-02,
        2.27449179e-01],...
```

Which is quite different from the first scaling, isn't it?
Why is that?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly is the problem with your current output? Values too big, too small, totally wrong...basically, what should it be and what is it instead?

Comment: @G.Anderson hello sir, I've updated my question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you checked the values yourself to see if the scaling is actually incorrect? It may be that there's a systematic bias in your data that means it's not distributed the same between your two samples. For example, what is the mean/mode/range/st.dev between the two sets calculated withou the scaler?